# Have multiple domains point to 1 PHP script

Tags: php, dns, nameservers

How would I make multiple domains point to 1 PHP script and have different content displayed depending upon the domain?

For example, lets say I have:

```
bearpaws.com
tigerteeth.com
```

I want these domains to point to my PHP script on `myapp.com/route.php`. Within my PHP script I could check the SERVER_NAME and display content based on that (if this is possible). However, I'm at a loss as to how I would set up the nameservers and whatnot.

I'd have a MySQL database containing the domain names and the content which should be displayed on each.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Serving multiple domains from the same directory is as simple as setting the same document root in your web server's configuration files. This has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: well as long as the dns is set to the same ip. are you on a VPS? shared host ?

Comment: @Dagon Doesn't even have to be the same IP if the server has multiple IP addresses.

Comment: true dat, this is probably better asked on: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: @Dagon I was thinking the same, but it *does* have some PHP related stuff in the question, just with no code. Vote to move, or vote too broad?

Comment: I'd like to make this work with a shared hosting provider first and scale hosting later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of Googling, heres how:

1. Create a subdomain like dns.myapp.com.
2. Have the index.php file for that subdomain be your script.
3. Create a CNAME record for the domain you want to point to the script, and have it point to dns.myapp.com.
4. ???
5. Profit.

Also, you can have them create a TXT record for the domain containing some verification code if you want that extra security.

Comment: I don't  see why you created a subdomain; but what ever works